# Python: how to find the first nonzero in a multi-series dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns indexed to date.  the data is consisted of 0's and 1's.  I would like to find the first nonzeros in each series and multiple it (and only it) by 100.

```
Date    A   B   C   D   E
3/1/16  0   0   0   0   0
3/2/16  0   0   1   0   0
3/3/16  1   0   0   0   0
3/4/16  0   1   0   0   0
3/7/16  0   0   1   0   1
3/8/16  0   0   0   0   1
3/9/16  0   0   0   1   1
```

I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
for col in df.columns:
    idx = df[col].first_valid_index()
    df[col][idx] = df[col][idx]*100.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `for` loop, we can do

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'Date']
for col in cols:
    idx = df[col][df[col] != 0].index[0]
    df[col][idx] = df[col][idx]*100
```

Comment: I think same rule is in pandas and r too - no loops ;)

Comment: Hello and welcome to pandas. It's nice to see fresh faces around here, so you get an upvote.

Comment: @jezrael  Thanks, I don't know all the functions in pandas to do a non-loop solution like you :=)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first for all numeric columns and then create boolean mask with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (same as `==`) with chain by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and compare too.

Then select by mask and multiple, last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date')

m = df.eq(1) & df.cumsum().eq(1)
df[m] *= 100

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     Date    A    B    C    D    E
0  3/1/16    0    0    0    0    0
1  3/2/16    0    0  100    0    0
2  3/3/16  100    0    0    0    0
3  3/4/16    0  100    0    0    0
4  3/7/16    0    0    1    0  100
5  3/8/16    0    0    0    0    1
6  3/9/16    0    0    0  100    1
```

Details:

```
print (df.cumsum())
        A  B  C  D  E
Date                 
3/1/16  0  0  0  0  0
3/2/16  0  0  1  0  0
3/3/16  1  0  1  0  0
3/4/16  1  1  1  0  0
3/7/16  1  1  2  0  1
3/8/16  1  1  2  0  2
3/9/16  1  1  2  1  3


print (df.cumsum().eq(1))
            A      B      C      D      E
Date                                     
3/1/16  False  False  False  False  False
3/2/16  False  False   True  False  False
3/3/16   True  False   True  False  False
3/4/16   True   True   True  False  False
3/7/16   True   True  False  False   True
3/8/16   True   True  False  False  False
3/9/16   True   True  False   True  False

print (df.eq(1))
            A      B      C      D      E
Date                                     
3/1/16  False  False  False  False  False
3/2/16  False  False   True  False  False
3/3/16   True  False  False  False  False
3/4/16  False   True  False  False  False
3/7/16  False  False   True  False   True
3/8/16  False  False  False  False   True
3/9/16  False  False  False   True   True
```

---

```
m = df.eq(1) & df.cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)
print (m)
            A      B      C      D      E
Date                                     
3/1/16  False  False  False  False  False
3/2/16  False  False   True  False  False
3/3/16   True  False  False  False  False
3/4/16  False   True  False  False  False
3/7/16  False  False   True  False  False
3/8/16  False  False  False  False   True
3/9/16  False  False  False   True  False
```

Setup:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Date   A   B   C   D   E
3/1/16  0   0   0   0   0
3/2/16  0   0   1   0   0
3/3/16  1   0   0   0   0
3/4/16  0   1   0   0   0
3/7/16  0   0   1   0   1
3/8/16  0   0   0   0   1
3/9/16  0   0   0   1   1"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
print (df)

     Date  A  B  C  D  E
0  3/1/16  0  0  0  0  0
1  3/2/16  0  0  1  0  0
2  3/3/16  1  0  0  0  0
3  3/4/16  0  1  0  0  0
4  3/7/16  0  0  1  0  1
5  3/8/16  0  0  0  0  1
6  3/9/16  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: And an upvote to you too, I was having difficulty with the second condition. There may be an alternative way too, with `idxmax`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you, `idxmax` was my first idea too, but here seems better is cumsum

Comment: See my answer, it is possible with argmax.

Comment: actually i want to test all the answers, can you guys post the code for creating the df? Better if there anyway to get a df from text. I think there is a workaound for this in R but don;t know  about python.

Comment: facing issue with clipboard, is there anyway to create df from variable?i tried `pd.read_table("""text,,,""", sep="\s+")`, it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I knew there was a way to use `argmax` here.

```
df = df.set_index('Date')

v = df.values
v[v.argmax(0), np.arange(df.shape[1] - 1)] *= 100  
df[:] = v

df.reset_index()



     Date    A    B    C    D    E
0  3/1/16    0    0    0    0    0
1  3/2/16    0    0  100    0    0
2  3/3/16  100    0    0    0    0
3  3/4/16    0  100    0    0    0
4  3/7/16    0    0  100    0    1
5  3/8/16    0    0    0    0  100
6  3/9/16    0    0    0  100    1
```

Had a little help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279363/4909087).