# 2D argmax on a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting with a numpy array `v`:

```
v = \
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

I want to find the first non-zero value in ***each column*** and multiply those values by 100.

My desired result is:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 100,   0,   0],
       [100,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 100,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   1,   0, 100],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   1],
       [  0,   0,   0, 100,   1]])
```

I thought to approach this problem by taking the argmax along each axis:

```
i = v.argmax(0)
j = v.argmax(1)
v[i, j] *= 100
```

I know I'm not using `i` and `j` correctly, so how can I fix this?

Comment: I think desired result is incorrect.  5th row?

Comment: @piRSquared I changed the question a bit... this is columnwise.

Comment: You don't need to find the argmax of rows if you want to find the `non-zero value in each column`. Does this work? `v[i, np.arange(5)] *= 100`

Comment: @umutto Yeah, that seems to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to range through the columns

```
v[v.argmax(axis=0), np.arange(v.shape[1])] *= 100
```

Comment: You beat me to it (-:

Comment: Didn't think this was so simple.

Comment: I think you want `v[(v != 0).argmax( . . . `, otherwise you'e multpliying the max value in each column by 100, not the first nonzero value (necessarily).

Comment: That is correct, but since 0*100 = 0, it doesn't really matter does it?

Comment: I'm just saying the question is looking for first nonzero, and if the original array isn't binary that's not what your code is doing now.